# R function and pass optional arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments

I create a R function like:

```
myfun <- function(x, function) function(x)
```

which obviously works now is for example

```
myfun(rnorm(10), round)
myfun(rnorm(10), sample)
```

Is it possible to pass over the argument `digits` from the function `round` without specifying it in `myfun`?
Or pass over the argument `replace` from the function `sample`?

Something like

```
myfun(rnorm(10), round(digits=2))
myfun(rnorm(10), sample(replacement=TRUE))
```

I know it looks strange. I want to write a function where i can choose the distribution in the body.

```
myfun <- function(n, function) function(n)
```

now `myfun(100,rnorm)` works of course, but can i use it for
`myfun(100,rt)` and define the degrees of freedom with argument `df` or
`myfun(100,rbinom)` and define the `size` and `prob`?

Comment: Please format your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `...`.

```
myfun <- function(x,function2, ...){function2(x,...)}
myfun(rnorm(10),round,digits=2)
 [1] -1.70  1.34  1.27 -0.42 -1.76 -0.40  0.59  1.10  0.41 -0.18
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed! Thank you very much!